# How can I compare spliced multidimensional arrays (with huge amount of data)?

Tags: php, multidimensional-array, associative-array, array-difference, array-splice

I have a huge array `$properties` with about 500.000 items:

```
  array(470000) {
    ["12345"]=>
    array(5) {
      ["dateTime"]=>
      string(19) "2016-10-12 19:46:25"
      ["fileName"]=>
      string(46) "monkey.jpg"
      ["path"]=>
      string(149) "Volumes/animals/monkey.jpg"
      ["size"]=>
      string(7) "2650752"
    }
    ["678790"]=>
    array(5) {
      ["dateTime"]=>
      string(19) "2016-10-12 14:39:43"
      ["fileName"]=>
      string(45) "elephant.jpg"
      ["path"]=>
      string(171) "Volumes/animals/elephant.jpg"
      ["size"]=>
      string(7) "2306688"
    }

... and so on.
```

So  to make performance better, I spliced it into parts:

```
$splice_size = 10000;
        $count_arr = (count($properties)/$splice_size)-1;


        For($i=0; $i<$count_arr; $i++){
            $res[] = array_splice($properties, 0,$splice_size); 
        }
        $res[] = array_splice($properties, 0,count($properties));
```

Now my array looks like this:

```
array(4) {
  [0]=>
  array(10000) {
    ["12345"]=>
    array(5) {
      ["dateTime"]=>
      string(19) "2016-10-12 19:46:25"
      ["fileName"]=>
      string(46) "monkey.jpg"
      ["path"]=>
      string(149) "Volumes/animals/monkey.jpg"
      ["size"]=>
      string(7) "2650752"
    }
    ["678790"]=>
    array(5) {
      ["dateTime"]=>
      string(19) "2016-10-12 14:39:43"
      ["fileName"]=>
      string(45) "elephant.jpg"
      ["path"]=>
      string(171) "Volumes/animals/elephant.jpg"
      ["size"]=>
      string(7) "2306688"
    }

   ... and so on.
   }
  [1]=>....
  and so on....
}
```

I want now compare two of these arrays:

```
  function array_diff_assoc_recursive($array1, $array2)
                {
                    foreach($array1 as $key => $value)
                    {
                        if(is_array($value))
                        {
                            if(!isset($array2[$key]))
                            {
                                $difference[$key] = $value;
                            }
                            elseif(!is_array($array2[$key]))
                            {
                                $difference[$key] = $value;
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                $new_diff = array_diff_assoc_recursive($value, $array2[$key]);
                                if($new_diff != FALSE)
                                {
                                    $difference[$key] = $new_diff;
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        elseif(!isset($array2[$key]) || $array2[$key] != $value)
                        {
                            $difference[$key] = $value;
                        }
                    }
                    return !isset($difference) ? 0 : $difference;
                }


                echo "<pre>";
                print_r(array_diff_assoc_recursive($new, $res));
                echo "</pre>";
```

But the system crashes. Too much data. So my question is, their must be an advantage of splicing the array (like making chunks) that I still do not get, to get better performance.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve by comparing them?

Comment: if there is a mistake for example. In one array it is `monkey` and in the other array it is `munkey`. Should be able to find it. Works well with smaller arrays. But big ones make problems

Comment: Using [`array_chunk`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-chunk.php) will make your code shorter, but I'm not convinced it's necessary. You end up duplicating the array into chunks which actually doubles the memory requirement. What I'd do is just a single loop through the already existing arrays

Comment: Why would you have the same values at more than one offset in the array? If you have "monkey" and "munkey" how do you know which one is wrong? Your explanation makes no sense.

Comment: @symcbean I'm assuming they have a 2nd array which has the same keys and might have slightly different values to some of the matching keys. That's the only way this makes sense to me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I were you I would just do:

```
$different = [];
$missingFrom2 = [];

foreach ($array1 as $key => $value) {
    if (!isset($array2[$key])) { $missingFrom2[] = $key; }
    if ($array2[$key] != $value) { $different[] = $key; }
}
$missingFrom1 = array_diff(array_keys($array2), array_keys($array1));
```

`$different` will be all keys which are different.

What you're doing seems a bit over-engineered for not particular benefit

Examples: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/7ff02f562e0591e8afb45ea51799b847fbc4063b
http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/402926605ba8a195d2dfc667be146654117cd078

Comment: tested your code but unfortunately my result is `array(0) {
}`  even if in array1 I wrote `monkey`  and in array2 I wrote `monkei`.

Comment: @Jarla http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/7ff02f562e0591e8afb45ea51799b847fbc4063b can you share what you've tried and didn't work?

Comment: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/3f3ce1faf28ba539fca6d75ecbd752a481c0ce1e

Comment: Is that the already chunked array? This answer works if you don't chunk the array

Comment: Ah, ok, this is the chunked array

Comment: Need solution for chunked array

Comment: I just wanted to point out in this answer that you don't need to chunk your array. It's unnecessary complexity and consumes more memory.

Comment: If I do not make the array into parts, I cannot compare it because it is too big. System crashes

Comment: I will try your solution